# how to make controller detect link down or host down in the following topology

Tags: networking, sdn, mininet, pox

I am trying to detect the traffic going to host(server) that is down.So as to redirect it to a working server.I am planning to implement the redirection part in click(nfv)
I run the controller using the following command  `./pox.py openflow.discovery forwarding.l2_learning`.
How to make controller detect the host down/link down.[image: Topology i am implimenting]

Answer (score 0):

i am able to detect host down with the following code

```
from pox.core import core
import pox
import pox.lib.packet as pkt
from pox.lib.revent import *
from pox.openflow.discovery import Discovery
from pox.host_tracker import host_tracker
import pox.openflow.libopenflow_01 as of

class kj_host(EventMixin):
  def __init__ (self):
    def startup ():
      core.openflow.addListeners(self, priority=0)
      core.openflow_discovery.addListeners(self)
      core.host_tracker.addListeners(self)
      """ Here is the place where is created the listener"""
    core.call_when_ready(startup, ('openflow','openflow_discovery', 'host_tracker'))


  def _handle_HostEvent (self, event):
    """ Here is the place where is used the listener"""
    print "Host, switchport and switch...", event.entry

  def _handle_PacketIn(self, event):
    """ Packet processing """
def launch():
  from host_tracker import launch
  launch()
  core.registerNew(kj_host)
```

I saved this code in `kj_host.py` and placed inside `/home/pox/pox/misc` and i run the controller with following command `./pox.py openflow.discovery forwarding.l2_learning misc.kj_host`
Reference:
1)[answer from github](https://github.com/noxrepo/pox/issues/180)
2)[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27433646/5706413)